# How to take multiple pictures using Android android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have the following code.

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( new File(path +"/image01.jpg") );
camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
camera_intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
startActivityForResult( camera_intent, 0 );
```

This launches the camera and saves the picture in the specified path. But I need to take more than one picture and specify the names of all of them, without exiting the camera activity.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592531/how-to-make-user-click-5-pics-and-display-it-in-different-image-view-in-android/42598225#42598225

I show the steps you need to take to capture multiple pictures from the camera without returning to your app between each picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the camera activity handles one pic at a time. But you could start it again from `onActivityResult()` until you get the required number of pics.