# How to force camera by intent to take picture automatically in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

i am creating an application.
and use device default camera to take picture.
using this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PICTURE);
```

in `onActivityResult()` method i call again above code and take [picture again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347594/how-to-take-multiple-pictures-using-android-android-provider-mediastore-action-i).

but i want to take multiple pictures at a time. is there any way to take picture automatically when camera is called by intent (not by creating custom camera activity).

Comment: You need to create your own camera;
[try this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image).

Answer (score 4):

By sending intent  you just say to existing camera application that it start and allow user to take picture - you are completely on the mercy of this application.  Some of them may contain some undocumented parameters allowing you to snap picture automcatically.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image

If you like to have control, you shall code camera application yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have to write your own custom camera, as there is no extra in [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) class that would allow taking another picutre.